# Missed lollipop update and now can't get it

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I ignored my lollipop update for Lenovo 6000 on approx 10 sep. and now i can't get it again..  I'm still trying to update but updater always says that it is the latest version . Now how to upgrade :-(

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings", "About Device"
You should see "Software Update"

Comment: I think by "updater" OP meant the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try lenovo smart assistant?? If you haven't its worth giving a try. Download lenovo smart assistant from this [link](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds101291) . Connect your phone to PC and check for updates. In case of any problems you can check instructions on download page.